# Client Not Receiving String From Server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to write a TCP client using Sockets in java, however I cannot seem to read data sent from the server to the client. Some time i will received from server but not all time..

```java
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "103.13.97.87"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8101;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }


                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");


            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

My CustomAdpter.java

```java
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList){

        mListItems = arrayList;

        //get the layout inflater
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //getCount() represents how many items are in the list
        return mListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
        //get the data of an item from a specific position
        //i represents the position of the item in the list
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
        //get the position id of the item from the list
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
        if (view == null) {
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
        String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);
        if (stringItem != null) {

            TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

            if (itemName != null) {
                //set the item name on the TextView
                itemName.setText(stringItem);
            }
        }

        //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
private TCPClient mTcpClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

    //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // connect to the server
    new connectTask().execute("");

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //String message = editText.getText().toString();
            String message = "mall: ABC Mall date: 08/08/2013 time: 13:45 md5 f6151b2cdc256be4971bcc30629bbc7\r\n";
           /* String str =md5Digest(message);
            String s=message+str;*/

            //add the text in the arrayList
            arrayList.add("c: " + message);

            //sends the message to the server
            if (mTcpClient != null) {


                mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);

                /*mTcpClient.sendMessage(s);*/
            }

            //refresh the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

}


public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
public static final String md5Digest(final String text)
{
     try
     {
           // Create MD5 Hash
           MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
           digest.update(text.getBytes());
           byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

           // Create Hex String
           StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
           int messageDigestLenght = messageDigest.length;
           for (int i = 0; i < messageDigestLenght; i++)
           {
                String hashedData = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                while (hashedData.length() < 2)
                     hashedData = "0" + hashedData;
                hexString.append(hashedData);
           }
           return hexString.toString();

     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
     {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return ""; // if text is null then return nothing
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you don't receive data from the server--do you get an error message of some sort? Did you follow my suggestion and confirm that the server is sending the data?

Comment: Woah. You can't `return null` in the `getItem(int)` method. The `ListView` actually uses that method to get the items.

Comment: what should i want to give instant of null?

Comment: public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mListItems.get(i);
    }

Comment: But some time i will get a result for the same code how?

Comment: I am not receiving error message but in my server client request is there how to solve this?

Comment: Any one find a solution for this i think bufferreader not reading my incoming data from server any other reader is available to read a data from server??