# Android TCP Client can not receive data from TCP Server with wifi

Tags: java, android, tcpclient

I have problem when I send/receive data between computer and android device with wifi module. My computer can send/receive data from android but android device can not receive data from computer it can send only what is wrong?
I set computer to TCP Server and android is TCP Client.
I think it error in DataInputStrem but I do not know to solve it.

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.1"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.writeUTF(message);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {
                //send the message to the server
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Log.e("TCP Client x", in.readUTF());
                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readUTF();
                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }
    //Declare the interface.
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is sendMessage called?  Without calling this, I don't see how you are sending messages.

Comment: Is there a sane reason you want to allow `mListener` to be `null`?

Comment: `in.readUTF()` can never return `null` and you don't need to `null` it out.

Comment: If you don't make `mRun` `volatile` there is not guarantee it will ever see another thread set it. http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2013/01/java-memory-model-and-optimisation.html

Comment: If you can make a `field` a local variable, you should do.  I would declare `String serverMessage` inside the loop, not as a field.

Comment: As your "Received Message" is after the loop, the message will only be printed once, only if you stop reading before the server disconnects and it will always be `null`.

Comment: For the first time open this app. Android device must send data to computer for request computer reply answer. If readUTF can not to return null.How to solve it?

Comment: You don't need to check for a value which will never happen.  You need to consider each of the points I gave you.  From the details given in the question it would appear you are not sending a message because you don't actually call sendMessage anywhere. I can't explain why you are not doing this.

Comment: How to solve what? It can't return null, period. Nothing to solve.

Comment: sendMessage call from mainActivity by click button after create object of TCPClient and I can see message from mainActivity.

Comment: My problem like this like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484119/client-not-receiving-string-from-server

Comment: That's not much use, as that question doesn't have an answer, probably because it's unclear. Note that it now has a vote to close on that score. You're going to have to clarify yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all answer and sorry for this question is not clear. My project is connect between Android device and electronic board by my electronic board include wifi module "HLKM03". I test connection by

1 I see data send/receive in client side(Android) with TCPClient application. and
2 I see data send/receive in server side(electronic board + Wifi Access point) so I check data tranfer by this solution "wifi+electronic board --> usb2RS232 --> computer(docklight program)". 
 From all. Now I can solve all my problem by change to this code

```
 try {
            //send the message to the server
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //Log.e("TCP Client x", in.readUTF());
            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                //serverMessage = in.readUTF();
                //TCPClient localClientActivity = TCPClient.this;
                int j = in.read(buffer);
                serverMessage = bytesToHexString(buffer, j);

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }
            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }
```

and add function chage bytetoHexString for convert data receive data from server. It can help my android receive data from my electronic board already. Thank you again.